# Problems related to Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries v2.1.10 NuGet update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Note: This question was totally rewritten several days after it was originally posted.

I have an ASP.NET MVC app developed in VS 2012, deployed to Azure.  The original projects were created from the ASP.NET MVC 4 project template.

NuGet recently started showing a whole slew of updated packages from Microsoft.  One of those updates, **Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries v2.1.10**, causes serious problems when it is installed.

1. It installs MicrosoftBcl.Build, which is not compatible with my Azure project (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180268/warning-all-projects-referencing-myproject-csproj-must-install-nuget-package-m) for the problem and its solution).
2. It causes a whole slew of "incompatible DLL" problems (see below).

This raises several burning questions:

1. My MVC app is just a website. It just runs in a web browser. Do I need this package at all? (E.g., is it used by template code, which would break, possibly subtly, if I remove the package?)
2. According to the Project Site (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/httpclient.aspx), there are a couple of newer (albeit beta) versions of this product. I assume I'd see them if I told NuGet to show me non-released versions. Do these versions fix the problems described above?

Here are the warnings I get when I build the solution after installing the updated NuGet package...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Ruby, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.4.3.0.13117\lib\net45-full\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "3.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "WebGrease, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [] to Version "1.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\WebGrease.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Data.OData, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "5.2.0.0" [] to Version "5.5.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.5.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.4.3.0.13117\lib\net45-full\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
1>  Ruby -> C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\Ruby\bin\Ruby.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Ruby.Azure, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>------ Publish started: Project: Ruby.Azure, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.7\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(220,5): warning : All projects referencing Ruby.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build.
3>      No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.4.3.0.13117\lib\net45-full\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "3.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "WebGrease, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [] to Version "1.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\WebGrease.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Data.OData, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "5.2.0.0" [] to Version "5.5.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.5.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.3.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.4.3.0.13117\lib\net45-full\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>      Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
3>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
3>      Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\Robert\Documents\SBSoftware\SCM\Ruby\Ruby\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
3>Ruby(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project 'Ruby' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
3>Ruby(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project 'Ruby' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
3>Ruby(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project 'Ruby' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
3>Ruby(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project 'Ruby' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
3>Ruby(0,0): warning WAT153: The web project 'Ruby' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
```

Comment: Did you read [Publish an MVC project as a web role to Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh369932.aspx#PublishMVC)?

Comment: In the development environment (not related to Azure in any way), adding Nuget packages that require `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` produces these same warnings.

Comment: I have this same problem in an MVC 4 app--except that I am NOT publishing to Azure...just a regular old Windows 2008 R2 Web Server.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [binding redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in your web.config file to solve issues.

For example, for line:

```
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.3.0.0"
```

Add in Web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet"
                              publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.3.0.0"
                             newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and so on... For each dll that creates exception add additional `dependentAssembly` node.

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster here (excpet that I am not pubilshing my app to Azure) and immediately added binding redirects.  It does not fix the problem.  It should...but it doesn't.

Comment: I had the same issue, also tried binding redirects with no luck. You need to explicitly use `dependentAssembly` as shown above rather than just a `bindingRedirect`.

Answer (score 4):

One situation which causes this error is running the Azure package oder publish commands without having done a clean rebuild for the same configuration (e.g. Release) before.

This fixed it for me:

1. Reinstall the WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet package by running the following command on the NuGet Package Manager Console:

   ```
   Update-Package –reinstall WindowsAzure.Storage
   ```
2. Rebuild the MVC web application project (Debug and Release).

If this does not help you could set the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" under TOOLS -> Options -> "Projects and Solutions" -> "Build and Run" to "Diagnostic" and check what causes the Assembly conflict (e.g. look for "Project file item includes which caused reference").

Comment: This answer did the trick for me with NuGet Package Restore. Switch to the publish configuration (Release in my case), Clean the Solution, Rebuild the Solution - may need to do twice in case of package restore. Then Publish to Azure works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to update/create an app.config file with the redirects as mentioned here:

https://cpaterson.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-assembly-consider-app-config-remapping-of-assembly/

Comment: Creating an `app.config` file & copying the redirects from my `web.config` got rid of the stupid warnings for me. Still doesn't make sense why I need an `app.config` file for an MVC project though. Oh well, I'm just glad to finally be rid of those pesky warnings!