# Build Error for UWP app Microsoft.Bcl.Build and packages.config next to the project file

Tags: win-universal-app

I am getting a strange build error when building Windows Universal apps.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not locate
>   C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\TT\Windows\MyCommonLibrary\packages.config. 
>   Ensure that this project has Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and
>   packages.config is located next to the project
>   file. MyApp

'MyApp' has a project reference to 'MyCommonLibrary'.

What is really weird is that even though it is displayed as a build 'error'. This does not effect my ability to build 'MyApp' or 'MyCommonLibrary'!

It also does not prevent me from deploying and running my app locally or otherwise. It is just a annoying to see this listed as a build error when it doesn't break the build!

Comment: I have same error and it prevents me to add some nuget packages. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2913 . We'll see what comes of it.

Answer (score 16):

I followed up with the Bcl.Build package owners and got a response from Eric St. John. He says that you shouldn't reference Bcl.Build in your UWP project that uses project.json, and there's a project property to suppress the warning that is telling you to do so.

> Correct, the problem is most of the packages out there that use it also don’t know about UWP either and if they update for UWP we want them to drop this dependency rather than make it work.  The package isn’t needed at all for UWP or any framework that supports project.json.
>
> To work around the error with the old package do the following:
>
> Add <SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences> to the  at the top of your csproj/vbproj

Comment: isn't this a general setting? will this cause any side affect for any other package?

Comment: Not strictly at the top I believe, should be in the ProjectReference section as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242424/1033684

Comment: Yes, the property should not be added to the top, because it fails to load the project file. I succeded adding this property to <PropertyGroup> section. It worked.

Comment: I added to both locations you guys mentioned, and also created an empty `PropertyGroup` and added it to it. The error message still appears.

Comment: should we add this property to the referenced project csproj file or the consumer?

Comment: I added the line in the first `<PropertyGroup>` node and solved the issue. 
For me the cause was that the main .csproj was saved in old xml format however referenced projects are in a new format.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a false positive from the [Nuget Update](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html) to 3.1.

For the time I solved it by creating the packages.config Visual Studio demands manually out of the existing project.json.

For instance:

**project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Bcl.Build": "1.0.21",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
</packages>
```

Comment: That worked alright but this created 8 additional warnings which I didn't have before. Any ideas? Also won't this conflict with Nuget since it's keeping these dependency references in its own config for a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to remove most of them, except for 2 which aren't describing the conflicting dependency but looking at detailed verbosity as we speak. i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="uap10.0" />
</packages>`.