# Azure Cloud Project warning: All projects referencing MyProject.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am using VS 2015. I have an Azure Cloud Project (a CCPROJ) which references a C# project (a CSPROJ). The C# project unfortunately must reference Microsoft.Bcl.Build due to a dependency that it has. However, when the cloud project builds, it gets this warning:

```
All projects referencing MyProject.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.  MyProject.Cloud
```

The problem here is that cloud projects cannot reference NuGet packages. Upon an internet search, I found this was reported to Microsoft at:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789839/unexpected-warning-when-building-solution-that-has-azure-cloud-services-and-a-reference-to-the-microsoft-bcl-build-nuget-package

But that report was closed as 'won't fix'. They gave a work-around, and actually referencing StackOverflow:

[warning : All projects referencing MyProject.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180268/warning-all-projects-referencing-myproject-csproj-must-install-nuget-package-m)

I tried the work-around out, in fact here is from my cloud project CCPROJ file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
      <Name>MyProject</Name>
      <Project>{77ACF4A4-5F19-40E9-991D-BDB09B175366}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
      <RoleName>MyProject</RoleName>
      <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
      <Properties>SkipValidatePackageReferences=true</Properties>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

As you can see I have the SkipValidatePackageReferences property set to true. Even with this, however, I still get the very same warning. My solution actually has multiple cloud projects and they all have the same problem. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have tried the usual - deleted my bin and obj directories, restarted Visual Studio, and machine. All I really want to do is suppress this annoying warning message.

Thanks

Comment: So I found if I go into my C# project (CSPROJ) and add <SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences> the warning goes away. But I don't want to specify this property when the C# project is built, only when the cloud project is being built - that is where the error occurs. All resources I've seen on the internet indicate that what I have should work within a ProjectReference. It makes me think that is something else out there stomping on my <Properties> element. How to debug that?

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution?